# How to recover files that have been deleted from shelf in tortoisehg program?

Tags: tortoisehg

I was trying to delete an individual file from my shelf and it turns out the delete button deletes all of the files in the shelf instead.  Is there a way to recover these files besides going into .hg/Trashcan and trying to remember which of those files were deleted?

Comment: I don't know for a fact, but your question saved me from losing some sleep. I made the same mistake but was able to recover the files from the trashcan.

Answer (score 34):

The best way to do this, as you alluded to, is to go into the `.hg/Trashcan` and copy the shelf file back into the `.hg/shelves` folder. Obviously if you order or list the trashcan folder by date you should be able to see which was the one you deleted by accident!

The `.hg` folder indicates the location you have clones your repository to. The `Trashcan` folder is inside it (may be hidden on some machines). The folder does not get created until you have deleted something.

Comment: Wish I could upvote this everytime I come here. See you in a couple of months.

Comment: For completion, recover using `hg import --no-commit [NAME].patch`.