# Where does mercurial keep shelved files?

Tags: mercurial

Unfortunately I've cleaned up my Mercurial shelves forgetting that I had some changes that I needed. I have regular file system backups, but don't know where Mercurial stores shelved files. Can someone please tell me where to look?

Mercurial version 3.3.2

I'm using mercurial from the cli and not TortoiseHg

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to recover files that have been deleted from shelf in tortoisehg program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17372525/how-to-recover-files-that-have-been-deleted-from-shelf-in-tortoisehg-program)

Comment: Close, but not exactly. I don't have a 'Trashcan' directory, but I do have a 'shelved' directory. Maybe because I used the cli and not tortoise? The shelved directory has a patch file in it, with the changes I was looking for.

Comment: FWIW, I recommend [Queues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mercurial_Queues) over Shelves.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are inside the `.hg` folder for your repository in a folder called `shelves`.

Note for TortoiseHg uses: Shelves deleted using the GUI will be moved into `.hg\Trashcan`