# How to recover .bak files from deleted shelf

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

So I accidentally deleted a shelf in TortoiseHg. I wanted to delete a certain file in it, but apparently it deletes the whole shelf.

Basically I did what OP did here: [How to recover files that have been deleted from shelf in tortoisehg program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17372525/how-to-recover-files-that-have-been-deleted-from-shelf-in-tortoisehg-program)
Now, I already had this happen to me (see my comment there), however now there isn't a single file in `.hg/Trashcan` but lots of `.bak` files.

How can I recover those `.bak` files?

Comment: Maybe you should post this on https://foss.heptapod.net/mercurial/tortoisehg/thg/-/issues which is the dedicated TortoiseHG issues list. Someone there might be able to help.